# TikzCD: everything is getting mashed together

Tags: tikz-cd

When I have a homotopy between two arrows, things seem to go nicely:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
 \begin{tikzcd} 
A
  \arrow[r, bend left=60, "F" ""{name=a, below}]
  \arrow[r, bend right=60, "G"', ""{name=b}]
 & B
  \arrow[Rightarrow, from=a, to=b, "\Theta"]
 \end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image] (The missing homotopy arrow appears to be a bug in my display. It should work fine on yours.)

But when I try two successive homotopies, everything gets mashed together:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{tikz-cd}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{center}
  \begin{tikzcd}
  A 
   \arrow[r, bend left=90, "F", ""{name=a, below}]
     \arrow[r, "G"', ""{name=b}]
     \arrow[r, bend right=90, "H"' ""{name=c}]
  & B
     \arrow[Rightarrow, from=a, to=b, "\Theta"]
     \arrow[Rightarrow, from=b, to=c, "\Psi"]
  \end{tikzcd}
  \end{center}
  \end{document}
```

[image]
How can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

 \begin{center}
 \tikzcdset{column sep/normal=3em}
  \begin{tikzcd}
  A
   \arrow[r, bend left=70, "F", ""{name=a, below}]
     \arrow[start anchor={[xshift=3ex]west}, end anchor={[xshift=-3ex]east},r, "G" pos=0.3, ""{name=b},""{name = bb, below}]
     \arrow[r, bend right=70, "H"', ""{name=c}]
  & B
     \arrow[Rightarrow, start anchor={[yshift=-0.75ex]north}, end anchor={[yshift=0.5ex]south}, from=a, to=b, "\Theta" pos = 0.4]
     \arrow[Rightarrow, start anchor={[yshift=-0.75ex]north}, end anchor={[yshift=0.5ex]south}, from=bb, to=c, "\Psi" pos = 0.35]
  \end{tikzcd}
  \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to move the labels $\Theta$, $\Psi$ down or up? I'm getting something like this, when I use a little more of a bend in the arrows. http://i.imgur.com/QZsYD45.png

Comment: Yes: instead of using `near start` or `near end`, you can specify `pos=…` (a value between 0 and 1). Please see my updated answer.